# div is not working in IE inside table definition

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

The `div` tag is not working inside table definition:

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
<div id="choice"><tr>
<td>-------</td>
<td>-------</td>
<td>-------</td>
<td>-------</td>
</tr></div>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

If I am trying---> `getElementById("choice").innerhtml="some data with td's"` is not working in IE browser?

But if I use `div`, by starting new table like,

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
<div id="choice"><table>
<tr>
<td>-------</td>
<td>-------</td>
<td>-------</td>
<td>-------</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

But can I make this with only one table, to run on IE.

Comment: as for me this markup is not valid

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: In place on div ,place an emtry <tr> and put <td>'s dynamically through script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table tag must follow a specific semantic. You can insert tags (divs and other ones) **only inside TD or TH**! It's not possible to insert any tag between table /table that are not one of the following: tr, td, th, thead, tbody, tfoot (and anyway you have to nest them properly!).
This is unfortunately a quite common mistake which can breaks table-structured form like:

```
<form>
  <table> 
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="foo" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
```

The above example its hard to debug... so pay attention in order to respect table semantic